# OpenGL rendering on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

In an attempt to build some other platforms besides Java/Dalvik on Android, I've disabled zygote and attempted the ideas listed here:

http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/index.html#opengl

I've successfully compiled the OpenGL test code and pushed it to the Android emulator (I'm running 2.3/gingerbread). Instead of the colored triangle, it just causes the boot screen with blinking "ANDROID_" text to flicker. Here's the output:

```
root@android:/data/misc # ./test1                                              
GL version: 1.4
Window specs: 0*0 format=-1416517231
GL context: 162f8
GL surface: 163d0
```

This seems to show that android_createDisplaySurface() from libui doesn't return a correctly sized window. But logcat on the emulator shows the following, which seems to imply the opposite:

```
D/libEGL  (   73): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emul.so
D/libEGL  (   73): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emul.so
D/libEGL  (   73): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emul.so
D/eglWrapper(   73): Loading egl dispatch for test1
D/eglWrapper(   73): isNeedEncode? for test1
D/eglWrapper(   73): Initializing native opengl for test1
D/eglWrapper(   73): loading /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so into /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emul.so complete
D/eglWrapper(   73): loading /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so into /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emul.so complete
I/gralloc (   73): using (fd=6)
I/gralloc (   73): id           = 
I/gralloc (   73): xres         = 320 px
I/gralloc (   73): yres         = 480 px
I/gralloc (   73): xres_virtual = 320 px
I/gralloc (   73): yres_virtual = 960 px
I/gralloc (   73): bpp          = 16
I/gralloc (   73): r            = 11:5
I/gralloc (   73): g            =  5:6
I/gralloc (   73): b            =  0:5
I/gralloc (   73): width        = 49 mm (165.877548 dpi)
I/gralloc (   73): height       = 74 mm (164.756760 dpi)
I/gralloc (   73): refresh rate = 651.04 Hz
I/pixelflinger(   73): Needs: n=0x03010144 p=0x00000177 t0=0x00000000 t1=0x00000000
I/ARMAssembler(   73): generated scanline__00000177:03010144_00000000_00000000 [ 26 ipp] (63 ins) at [0x4009f1e8:0x4009f2e4] in 9552233 ns
```

My only guess so far is that perhaps something on the stack is waiting on SurfaceFlinger, which is not running without Dalvik. But it's not in the logs.

I realize this is off the beaten path, but hope some android/OpenGL pros might have some clues as to what's going on. Any help sincerely appreciated.

Comment: It has been some time and no answer was posted to this problem. I am also having this problem and am struggling to find a solution. If you solved this, please could you post your answer here. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android native surface has been changed since eclair or froyo. You should try  [framework/base/opengl/tests/angeles/app-linux.cpp](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=opengl/tests/angeles/app-linux.cpp;h=4d10ee509924cd751d4b3286983695894ac99bef;hb=refs/heads/gingerbread).